# C# Interactive not recognizing ValueTuple reference

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I cannot use tuples in the C# Interactive window; I get the following error:

```
(1,15): error CS8137: Cannot define a class or member that utilizes tuples because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TupleElementNamesAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
(1,15): error CS8179: Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is not defined or imported
(2,9): error CS0103: The name 'IsLiteralTypeName' does not exist in the current context
(2,47): error CS8179: Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is not defined or imported
(5,12): error CS8179: Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is not defined or imported
```

This even after I've added a reference to the ValueType assembly:

```
#r "D:\MyProject\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.3.1\lib\netstandard1.0\System.ValueTuple.dll"
```

How can I make use of value tuples from the C# Interactive window?

Comment: Add Nuget package System.ValueTuple ?

Comment: @EmanuelPirovano How do I add a Nuget package for the C# interactive window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Remove `/r:System.ValueTuple.dll`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17157) from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<edition>\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\InteractiveComponents\CSharpInteractive.rsp
```

for Visual Studio 2017 and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<edition>\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csi.rsp
```

for the command line tool (csi.exe)