# Upgraded to .Net Standard 2, now project says reference isnt there

Tags: visual-studio, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I just upgraded a .Net Standard 1.4 PCL dll to .Net Standard 2.0.  I am trying to write a method that returns a ValueTuple and I get the error:

```
Cannot define a class or member that utilizes tuples because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TupleElementNamesAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
```

But it is...kind of.  Below is what my project.json says:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "2.0.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.3",
    "System.Collections.Specialized": "4.3.0",
    "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.4.0",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.3.2",
    "System.Reflection": "4.3.0",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.3.0",
    "System.ServiceModel.Primitives": "4.4.0",
    "System.ValueTuple": "4.4.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard2.0": {}
  }
}
```

But when I expand my references for the project, I notice a couple packages aren't listed.

[image]

Ive tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306204/c-sharp-interactive-not-recognizing-valuetuple-reference) with no success.

edit:  I am using VS 2017

Comment: VS2015 or VS2017?

Comment: @LexLi VS2017..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get around this SNAFU so I ended up just creating a brand new project based on .net standard 2.0.  Copied all my files over to the new project and added it as a reference to all my projects.  It trashed my resharper, but everything else works.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem as well. Turns out my .csproj file had the lines below, even though the version referenced was .NET Core 2.0. I removed these lines and the project built successfully.

```
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
```